# Commits pushed to Github through Github Desktop App(Windows) not showing up

Tags: windows, git, github

I created two repositories through the Github website about a couple of hours ago. Then I went to the Github Desktop App, and made many commits to each of those two repositories. The process I had followed was:

1. Create repository on Github website
2. Go to Github Desktop App, and hit "clone" for the selected repository
3. The repository was cloned to a "Github" folder in "Documents"
4. Then I copied over my code files to each of the repository folders (through Windows explorer)
5. In the Github Desktop App, I automatically got the "x uncommited changes" for the number of files I had copied over.
6. I added a message in the "summary" and "description" section, and clicked on the "Commit" button at the end, and a blue check mark appeared.

However, now that I'm on another (ubuntu) computer and wanted to clone the 2 repositories on this, it appears that none of my commits were ever pushed to Github. The Github website also just shows the 2 repositores I had created at the very beginning, intialized with a readme.md. There's nothing else.

What went wrong?

Comment: I don't see any point here at which you "pushed" your changes back to GitHub.  I'm not familiar with the desktop app, but I suspect you're missing a step.  According to [these docs](https://help.github.com/desktop/guides/contributing/committing-and-reviewing-changes-to-your-project/) there should be a "sync" button for this purpose.

Comment: there is a **Sync** button.  I've downloaded the desktop app on my Mac, and it's right there in the upper right.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Create repository on Github website
2. Go to Github Desktop App, and hit "clone" for the selected repository
3. You should copy all your files to cloned repository.
4. Click to view all uncommited changes.
5. You have to write the summary and description and hit the button 'commit to "your branch name"'.
6. And as a final step, you should push 'Sync button' at the upper right corner.

Comment: Thank you Ninjava! I forgot hitting that sync button on step 6 looks like I won't be forgetting that anymore ;)

Comment: Perfect --- Kudos to the sync button. Really helped me not going crazy. Thanks for the information...